# Django: adding model to admin site

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I dont know what i am doing wrong but i cant add model to my admin .

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.admindocs',
'RM.cal',
'release',
'south',
```

)

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
'django_notify.middleware.NotificationsMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
```

)

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
        global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS +
        ('django.core.context_processors.request','django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',)

 )
```

admin.py

```
from cal.models import *
from django.contrib import admin
admin.site.register(Cos)
```

urls.py

```
 from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Example:
# (r'^RM/', include('RM.foo.urls')),
(r'^cal/', include('RM.cal.urls')),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': 'C:/Users/sg0217297/Desktop/test/tkt_crmt/RM/media'}),
```

models.py its new field just for testing but i can add it to admin  ;/

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
class Cos(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank= False , null = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

Any idea why ??

Thanks for help

E:
Updated urls.py

Comment: when you run syncdb does it work ok? And does the admin site show ok aside from the missing model?

Comment: Which urls.py you are showing here? `patterns('RM.cal.views' ...` doesn't seem to be appropriate for admin urls.

Comment: Im using south migration  i cant create new datebase . Yes in admin site i see other models but this one (dunno why) i dont see ...

Comment: but your migration works ok, and the model is definitely created in the db?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an app_label in your class, django only looks 1 level deep for models.py, so:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    # whatever

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'cal'
```

You can also import the 2nd level models within the **init** of the module above

Comment: Hmm i added to my models field this and it not working ;/ 

Im not using app_label in other ModelFields and they are in admin site ;/

Answer (score 0):

try to import  indivisual models instead of '*' :

```
from your_app.models import model1,model2
```